# Is there anyway to compile many files by a single instruction in Linux bash?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, wildcard

For example, in Linux, gonna compile 3 files "test1.c", "test2.c" and "test3.c" separately to "test1", "test2" and "test3", is there a way using wildcard or pipe to do it by one line bash instruction?

Comment: `for f in test?.c; do gcc "$f"& done`

Comment: @WilliamPursell The `a.out` will get overwritten 

Comment: Or maybe write a genuine Makefile

Comment: @LéaGris Good suggestion - the command will be the shortest and it will save resources if not everything needs rebuilding.

Comment: Even without a makefile (default rules should work), you could do `for i in test?.c; do make ${i%.c}; done`

Comment: With bash, you could do `files=(test*.c); make "${files[@]%.c}"`, which would allow you to use options to get parallel builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really such a thing as a *"bash instruction"*, and even if you say *"bash command"*, then `gcc` isn't really such a thing either because it is not intrinsically related to, or a part of `bash`. It is a separate binary/program that can be run under any shell, such as `sh`, `ksh`, `ash`, `dash` or even `tcsh`.

Assuming you mean one line, you can do:

```
gcc prog1.c -o prog1 & gcc prog2.c -o prog2 & gcc -o prog3 prog3.c
```

You can equally do that in a loop as William was suggesting:

```
for f in test?.c; do gcc "$f" -o "${f%.c}" &  done
```

IMHO though, the easiest is with **GNU Parallel**:

```
parallel gcc {} -o {.} ::: test?.c
```

There are those who will rightly say that **GNU Parallel** is not part of POSIX, but, to be fair, you didn't mention POSIX in your question. So, if POSIX-compliance is an issue, you may choose to  avoid this suggestion.

---

As suggested in the comments, a `Makefile` would be even better, So if you create a file called `Makefile` with the following contents:

```
all: test1 test2 test3
```

You can simply run:

```
make
```

and all three programs will be compiled, only if necessary, i.e. if you have changed the source file since last compiling. Or, if you want to use all those cores that you paid Intel so handsomely for, you can do them in parallel with:

```
make -j
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Really learn a lot from your ans